# Update a variable every 5 second using jquery

Tags: python, jquery, html, django, ajax

I am using django to create a webpage and this is the first time I am doing so. I am trying to fetch the value of a variable from .py file at an interval of 5 seconds. Below is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Like Post App</title>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "display-3 color-red"><center>DataFlair AJAX Tutorial<br>Post APP</center></div>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class = 'container jumbotron'>
        <h3 class="display-5">{{ forloop.counter }}. {{ post.post_heading }}</h3>
<p class="lead">{{ post.post_text }} </p>
        <p>
        <div type="text/css" class = "container">Author : {{ post.post_author }}</div>
        <a class="likebutton btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="like{{ post.id }}" data-catid="{{ post.id }}">Like({{ post.like_ref.counter }})</a> </p> <p id="message{{post.id}}">
</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}

<script type="text/javascript">

              setInterval(function() {
                    getvalue(); // Do something every 5 seconds
              }, 5000);

getvalue();
              function getvalue(){

                      var id;
                      id = $(this).attr("data-catid");
                      $.ajax(
                        {
                          type:"GET",
                          url: "like",
                          data:{
                             post_id: id
                                },
                      success: function( data )
                      {
                          $( '#like'+ id ).text("Like(" + data +")");
                          var i=parseInt(data);
                          console.log("Value= "+i);
                      }
                    }
                  )
                }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the views.py code:

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post, Like
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
#DataFlair #AJAX_tutorial
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'post/index.html', { 'posts': posts })
def like(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']
        likedpost = Post.objects.get(id = post_id )
        m = Like.objects.filter( post=likedpost ).first()
        m.counter +=1
        m.save()
        value1= int(m.counter)
        #data1= {'cmd': 'success', 'ctr': str(m.counter) }
        return HttpResponse(value1)
        #return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data1))


    else:
        return HttpResponse("unsuccesful")
```

I keep getting the following errors:
1) GET http://localhost:8000/ajax/like/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
2) GET http://localhost:8000/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

Please help.

Comment: The `favicon.ico` error is unrelated to your problem. Many websites have this error because the browser automatically tries to download `favicon.ico` to be able to show it in the browser tab. The "500 internal server error" means your python script had an error. Can you post more details?

Comment: Check your server log for the reason for the 500 error.

Answer (score 2):

I believe:

```
id = $(this).attr("data-catid");
```

is not pointing to the button... maybe you should try:

```
id = $(".likebutton").attr("data-catid");
```